# How to transform invalid JSON data in Logic Apps?

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to create the workflow to send email in Logic Apps.
I transform Parquet to JSON in a Synapse Pipeline because I want to use "create HTML table" component from JSON file, but the created JSON format looks invalid.
The invalid JSON is below.

```
{"Name":"A","Age":20,"ID":"1"}
{"Name":"B","Age":25,"ID":"2"}
{"Name":"C","Age":30,"ID":"3"}
{"Name":"D","Age":18,"ID":"4"}
{"Name":"E","Age":45,"ID":"5"}
{"Name":"F","Age":55,"ID":"6"}
```

I think that I need to transform this JSON to like below but I have no idea how should I do.

```
[
{"Name":"A","Age":20,"ID":"1"},
{"Name":"B","Age":25,"ID":"2"},
{"Name":"C","Age":30,"ID":"3"},
{"Name":"D","Age":18,"ID":"4"},
{"Name":"E","Age":45,"ID":"5"},
{"Name":"F","Age":55,"ID":"6"}
]
```

Actually, I tried to use "Compose" activity but the output was invalid JSON.
[image: overview]
Compose Function

```
concat('[',variables('test'),']')
```

Compose Output(cannot insert comma)

```
[﻿{"Name":"A","Age":20,"ID":"1"}
{"Name":"B","Age":25,"ID":"2"}
{"Name":"C","Age":30,"ID":"3"}
{"Name":"D","Age":18,"ID":"4"}
{"Name":"E","Age":45,"ID":"5"}
{"Name":"F","Age":55,"ID":"6"}]
```

Do you have any idea?
Any answer would be helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try the expression below, it uses a [split](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#split) and a [join](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#join) to add the comma to each item of your string. With a [json](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#json) function your can turn the string into json.

```
json(concat('[',join(split(variables('Test'), concat('}',decodeUriComponent('%0A'),'{')), concat('}',',',decodeUriComponent('%0A'),'{')), ']'))
```

Comment: Hi, @Expiscornovus.
I tried your suggestion but Logic App returns the error.
`Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Compose' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'json' parameter is not valid. The provided value '[{"Name":"A","Age":20,"ID":"1"} {"Name":"B","Age":25,"ID":"2"} {"Name":"C","Age":30,"ID":"3"} {"Name":"D","Age":18,"ID":"4"} {"Name":"E","Age":45,"ID":"5"} {"Name":"F","Age":55,"ID":"6"}]' cannot be parsed: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 1, position 1.'. .`

Comment: Can you use the compose outputs directly in the Create HTML table. You don't need the parse json action after you have converted it to an array in the Compose action.

Comment: Btw, I was splitting on the line feed character as well (%0A). It is possible it is not a newline but just a space. Can you also try this expression to see if that makes a difference? `json(concat('[',join(split(variables('Test'), '} {'), '}, {'), ']'))`

Comment: @Exiscornovus
Thank you for your reply.
The problem was very simple.
The JSON converted by Synapse contained a BOM, and I removed it on the Synapse side.
Then it worked.
Thank you for your kindness.